# Values are not setting to logic iterate

Tags: java, jsp

i have three logic iterates in my jsp, actually where the error occurs is when i fill the wrong data and submit its shows the error, but the list which am setting to the logic iterate is not population in the JSP, but i have the values in the list as the list not setting the logic iterate didnt work.

```
<TR increment="<%=row++%>"  bgcolor="lightblue" id="rel<%= element2.getID()%>" style="<%= (element2.getIsRetrive()==0) ? "display:''" : "display:'none'" %>" >
  <TD align="center" id="<%= element2.getID()%>">&nbsp;

 <html:select property="companyID"  styleId="ID"  name="element2" indexed="true"    >
        <html:options collection="IDList" property="value"/>
  </html:select>

  <TD align="center">&nbsp;

    <html:select property="Type"   name="element2" indexed="true">
            <html:options collection="TypeList" property="value"/>

  </html:select>
  </TD>
```

setup form in sampleForm.java, am getting the values for the list. but its not passing to logic iterate

```
protected Vector sampleList = new Vector();


/**
 * @return the sampleList
 */
public Vector getsampleList() {
    return sampleList;
}

/**
 * @param sampleList the sampleList to set
 */
public void setsampleList(Vector sampleList) {
    this.sampleList = sampleList;
}
```

in action class am setting the list like this

```
sampleForm.setSampleList(sampleList);
```